# What is the equivalent for pycassa ColumnFamily.get_range() with Lazyboy?

Tags: python, database, nosql, cassandra

I think everything is in the question.
I'm looking for the Lazyboy equivalent for Pycassa ColumnFamily.get_range() -- with features like column_start, column_finish et column_count --.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this file in lazyboy:

http://github.com/digg/lazyboy/blob/master/lazyboy/iterators.py

it has a few different range methods.

E.g., line 121: def key_range(key, start="", finish="", count=100):

or you could use this when you need to apply slice predicates:

def slice_iterator(key, consistency, **predicate_args):

HTH